# AVCaptureSession Image Is Size Of Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, avcapturesession

I'm using AVCaptureSession to create a camera and I'm trying to take a picture with it. Here is the code that loads the camera...

```
func reloadCamera() {

    cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (camera == false) {
        let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        for device in videoDevices {
            let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
                captureDevice = device
                break

            } else {
                captureDevice = backCamera
            }
        }

    } else {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    }

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        if captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                captureSession!.startRunning()

            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle any errors
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Here is how I take a photo...

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){
    toggleFlash()

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = (previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation)!
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in


            if sampleBuffer != nil {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)

                self.capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

                if self.camera == true {
                    self.capturedImage = UIImage(CGImage: self.capturedImage.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                } else {
                    self.capturedImage = UIImage(CGImage: self.capturedImage.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)

                }



                self.tempImageView.image = self.capturedImage

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.capturedImage, nil, nil, nil);

                self.tempImageView.hidden = false
                self.goButton.hidden = false
                self.cameraView.hidden = true
                self.removeImageButton.hidden = false
                self.captureButton.hidden = true
                self.flashChanger.hidden = true
                self.switchCameraButton.hidden = true

            }


        })
    }
}
```

But what's happening is the picture that is taken is as large as the entire screen (like Snapchat), but I only want it to be as big as the UIView I'm taking it from. Tell me if I you need any more information. Thank you!

Comment: "But what's happening is the picture that is taken is as large as the entire screen" Actually I would expect it to be much larger than that. How do you know how big it is? I don't see any code that captures a picture or does anything with the captured picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are the one who is setting the capture session's preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh. If you don't need that, don't do that; use a smaller-size preset. For example, use AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 to get a smaller size.

Second, no matter what the size of the resulting photo may be, reducing it to the size you need, and displaying it at that size, is entirely up to you. Ultimately, it's just a matter of the size and content mode of your image view, though it is always better to reduce the image size as well, in order to avoid wasting memory (as you would be doing by displaying an image that is significantly larger then what the user is shown).

Comment: I just updated my question to show how I take the picture, but how would I make it so that it crops out the rest of the picture?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it crops out the rest of the picture". You have shown only this line: `self.tempImageView.image = self.capturedImage` Okay, so now we know it has something to do with an image view. But you have not said anything about the settings of that image view (how it is sized, what its content mode is, whether it clips to bounds — all of which is crucial). Under auto layout, the default behavior is that the image view takes on the size of its image, so from what I understand, what you are seeing is more or less the behavior I would expect.

Comment: It's set to aspect fill and I don't clip to bounds, but regardless, I do need to save the image as it is shown in the UIImageView, and clipToBounds only modifies the image for the UIImageView.

Comment: "I do need to save the image as it is shown in the UIImageView" Aha. Did you know that this is the first time you've clarified that little fact? If that is the question - how to save an image at the size / cropping that is displayed in an image view - then that is the question you should ask.

Comment: Okay sorry for being so unclear, I should've formulated a better question. But could you help me out please?

Comment: What I suggest is that you ask a whole new question. Forget the capture session, the capture, etc. Just say you've got an image showing in an image view and you want to save an image _of_ that image view. It's easy to do, but comments are not the place to discuss it. Ask a new question. It's free and easy to do.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you. (: